# Is PSeq the correct approach to use in F# 3.0?

Tags: f#, parallel-processing

I've been using the F# powerpack for some time and it's got the great PSeq module in and it works really well.

However it doesn't smell correct as this is an extension to the F# libraries, rather than a standard library. Is there a more 'correct' way to perform general parallelism in F#?

I know this is quite a general question, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere else that is recent (eg 2013)

Comment: Well, `PSeq` from F# PowerPack seems to be a thin wrapper over `ParallelQuery<T>`, which makes it F# mirror of `ParallelEnumerable`. Considering there's only `Array.Parallel` module and the fact that `ParallelEnumerable` is already built into the framework, I see no reason not to use it (either directly or via F#-friendly wrapper). It is a part of the default .NET ecosystem after all...

Comment: The short answer is yes :-) (provided that the structure of the data and of your processing is such that using PLINQ will actually work efficiently on that).

Comment: Thanks Tomas - I hoped this would be the case, but really wonder why PSeq isn't a builtin module

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the `PSeq` module is just a thin wrapper over [the Parallel LINQ library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The main purpose is to give you a nice syntax, compatible with pipelining and the style used with `Seq` and other standard modules.

So, if Parallel LINQ is the right thing in your case, then `PSeq` module is the best way to use it from F#. That said, PLINQ only improves the performance if your collections have the right structure - you need to process fairly large collections and the operations that you are running are non-trivial (otherwise, there is a lot of overhead).

Also, the easiest way to use `PSeq` is probably just to copy `PSeq.fs` and `PSeq.fsi` into your project (they are part of the F# PowerPack, but if you only care about `PSeq`, then copying the two files is all you need).